# 32 bit oracle libraries working in Visual Studio but not SSMS

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssms

I have an SSIS package that I've developed in Visual Studio 2015.
The package is connected to an Oracle DB and a local SQL Server DB as input and output respectively.
I had some issues connecting the package to the Oracle client in the past due to 32 vs 64 bit compatibility issues (machine is 64 bit, Visual Studio is 32 bit).

I fixed that by installing both 32 and 64 bit oracle libraries on my machine and changing the Project property 'Run64BitRuntime' to False.

However, I've now exported the project as a .ispac file to SSMS to try schedule it. However, I'm getting the error I had with Visual Studio a while back, "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit oracle client components installed".

Visual Studio and SSMS are both 32 bit applications, so why is this issue popping up again? My project should be set to use 32 bit libraries by the looks of it and runs fine in VS.
Does SSMS have it's own toggle for which driver to use?

Comment: How did you install 32 and 64 bit Oracle Client? Follow this instruction to make it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: If they're not installed properly, why do I no longer have issues with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve the problem somehow. You can change the package execution settings in SSMS under advanced settings.

You can also choose what settings you want to run in a scheduled job so this allows me to run all the packages at 32-bit runtime.

[Picture here showing which option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBoEE.png)